# Character to integer conversion off for alphabet characters

Tags: c

I'm converting a character string character by character into integers. So 'A' - '0' should be 10. However even though the numbers come out fine, alphabetical characters (i.e. A-F) come out as being off by 7. For instance, here's my line of code for conversion:

```
result = result + (((int) (*new - '0')) * pow(16, bases));
```

If I print that line piece by piece for a hex string like "A2C9" then for some reason my A is converted to 17 and my C is converted to 19. However the numbers 2 and 9 come out correctly. I'm trying to figure out if I'm missing something somewhere.

Comment: You realize that 'A'..'F' aren't even guaranteed to be consecutive, much less consecutive immediately before or after the '0'..'9' digits,  right? The ASCI decimal code point for 'A' is 65, for '0' it is 48. Thus 'A' - '0' is 65-48 = 17. You may find [this ASCI chart](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) enlightening, but [this non-asci](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) table even more interesting for why you cannot portably do this how you're attempting to.

Comment: Yeah that was foolish of me. Thanks for the help on that. @WhozCraig

Comment: No worries, sir. Everyone figures it out sooner or later. Jonathan's answer covers it very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASCII code for 'A' is 65; for 'Z', it is 90.
The ASCII code for '0' is 48; for '9', it is 57.  These codes are also used in Unicode (UTF-8), 8859-x, and many other codesets.

When you calculate `'A' - '0'`, you get 65 - 48 = 17, which is the 'off-by-seven' you are seeing.

To convert the alphabetic characters 'A' to 'F' to their hex equivalents, you need some variation on:

```
c - 'A' + 10;
```

Remembering that 'a' to 'f' are also allowed and for them you'd need:

```
c - 'a' + 10;
```

Or you'd need to convert to upper-case first.  Or you can use:

```
const char hexdigits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

int digit = strchr(hexdigits, toupper(c)) - hexdigits;
```

or any of a myriad other techniques.  This last fragment assumes that `c` is known to contain a valid hex digit.  It fails horribly if that is not the case.

Note that C does guarantee that the codes for the digits 0-9 are consecutive, but does not guarantee that the codes for the letters A-Z are consecutive.  In particular, if the codeset is EBCDIC (mainly but not solely used on IBM mainframes), the codes for the letters are not contiguous.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I didn't realize I was making such a rookie mistake. Lesson learned. Thanks Jonathan (and everyone else).

Answer (score 2):

You are subtracting ASCII values. That is fine for A-Z and for 0-9, but not if you start mixing them. Read about the ASCII table to better understand the issue.

Here is the table:
http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif